# Are SSD more energy efficient than eMMC and microSD?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I'm wanting to build a mobile platform with a battery, and I've looked up some sites about the various types of Flash\NAND based devices.  Reliability and speed goes to SSD over USB Flash, NAND, and eMMC.  But what about power requirements?

Are SSD more energy efficient than eMMC and microSD?

Comment: I think a major reason why this question hasn't attracted any answers is that it seems to be based on basically a false premise, and is phrased in a way that does not invite alternative answers. eMMC and MicroSD cards *are both solid state storage devices* and thus technically fall into the category "SSD". Also many SSDs are implemented using NAND flash memory, and of course USB is an interface and *for the purposes of this question* is basically on par with SATA, SCSI or IDE/PATA (having negligible impact on either reliability or power consumption for a device).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking up more info about all 3 technologies and that, sadly, no one has answered, I think I have a proper answer.

THIS FREAKIN ARTICLE I MISSED!

[Which consumes more power: hard drive or SD card/card reader?](https://superuser.com/questions/282202/which-consumes-more-power-hard-drive-or-sd-card-card-reader/282227#282227)

SSD's use almost the same or more juice as a HDD, with its superior performance still winning out.

MicroSD's are prone to failure more readily and not meant to be used as regular Hard Drives.  Backup OFTEN.

Comment: *"SSD's use almost the same or more juice as a HDD"* I find that hard to believe, considering that a SSD has no need for spinning materials at hurricane wind speeds. Consider [this summary](http://www.anandtech.com/show/7173/samsung-ssd-840-evo-review-120gb-250gb-500gb-750gb-1tb-models-tested/11) for example, and note that traditional hard disk drives will normally draw on the order of 5-10W. The *worst* of those figures are on the order of what a *low powered* HDD needs.

Comment: FINALLY there's a response.  As for the powers issue, I've seen people on both sides arguing about power management for SSD's.  Saying that it uses the same as HDD, uses MUCH less power than one, uses SLIGHTLY less power, and sometimes uses MORE.  There was a lot of mixed results in Google searches I found that I kinda threw my hands up and gave up on it since I couldn't find a reliable article.  You've found the first one that wasn't BS.

Comment: There's also [this summary](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/samsung-840-evo-review-1tb-ssd,3567-13.html). And [here](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/ssd-recommendation-benchmark,3269-7.html) as well. I don't know what you searched for, but when my trusty retailer failed to produce power consumption figures for SSDs, I simply plugged "ssd power consumption" (without the quotes) into Google and those were among the top hits. If you're willing to consider manufacturer's web sites, there's also e.g. [this from OCZ](http://ocz.com/consumer/ssd-guide/ssd-vs-hdd) in that same list of hits.

Comment: Very good, but one thing that was still left unanswered is, is it still more efficient than the best microSD's on the market?

http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00D6XTMFC?ie=UTF8&tag=craetive-20&linkCode=xm2&camp=1789&creativeASIN=B00D6XTMFC

That is a 64 GB microSDXC Class 10 UHS-I Memory Card that has "Up to 80/50MB/s read/write speed".  How does that stack up against an SSD in power consumption?